# About a type of variable and its objection to a class in polymorphism

Tags: java, c#, oop, object, interface

```
class Animal {
  public void animalSound() {
    System.out.println("The animal makes a sound");
  }
}

class Pig extends Animal {
  public void animalSound() {
    System.out.println("The pig says: wee wee");
  }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  public void animalSound() {
    System.out.println("The dog says: bow wow");
  }
}

class MyMainClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Animal myAnimal = new Animal();  // Create a Animal object
    Animal myPig = new Pig();  // Create a Pig object
    Animal myDog = new Dog();  // Create a Dog object
    myAnimal.animalSound();
    myPig.animalSound();
    myDog.animalSound();
  }
}
```

So my question here is; myAnimal is an Animal type variable and points to Animal() class, it's all okay here, what about myPig? myPig is an Animal type variable but points to Pig class, does that mean myPig is going to cast or use whatever in its **TYPE** class (in this case Animal), but because of it points to Pig class, it's invoking in its pointing class right(in Pig class)?

.
.
.
.
.

```
    interface IAnimal
    {
        void animalSound(); // interface method (does not have a body)
    }

    class AnimalSound
    {
        private IAnimal _animal;

        public AnimalSound(IAnimal animal)
        {
            _animal = animal;
        }

        public void animalVoice()
        {
            _animal.animalSound();
        }
    }

    class Pig : IAnimal
    {
        public void animalSound()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Pig pig!");
        }
    }

    class Dog : IAnimal
    {
        public void animalSound()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Dog dog!");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AnimalSound myAnimal = new AnimalSound(new Dog());  // Create a Pig object
            myAnimal.animalVoice();
        }
    }
```

And lastly, I don't get this pattern, it requires us an interface to work with but we give it a class which implements an interface, how and why does this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> myPig is an Animal type variable but points to Pig class

It would be better to say that myPig is a Animal **reference** that refers to a Pig **object**.

> myPig is going to cast or use whatever in its TYPE class (in this case Animal), but because of it points to Pig class, it's invoking in its pointing class right(in Pig class)?

There is no casting going on. Casting converts a reference of one type to a reference of another type. In this case we simply call a method on the reference. The behavior will depend on the if the method is **virtual** or not.

- Virtual methods will use the **object type** to resolve the method, i.e. *"The pig says: wee wee"*.
- Non virtual methods use the **reference type**, i.e. *"The animal makes a sound"*.

Search for "dynamic dispatch" for further reading.

in c# methods are non-virtual by default, in java they are virtual per default. Java declared non virtual methods with `final` while c# declares virtual method with `virtual` in the base class and `override` in the derived class.

An interface is similar to a base class. The difference is that all interface methods are virtual, and have to be defined in the derived class. The dispatching mechanism is otherwise the same. So you can never create a `IAnimal` object, it has to be a `Pig` or `Dog`.